# Solving a system of two second order ODEs using Runge-Kutta method (ode45) in MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to solve the system of differential equations outlined in Von Karman's rotating disk flow. I got them into a system of ordinary differential equations:

F(n), G(n), H(n)

$$F'' = -G^2 + F^2 - F'H$$
$$G'' = 2FG - HG'$$
$$H'  = -2F$$

with boundary conditions $F(0) = 0$, $G(0) = 1$, $H(0)=1$, $F(\infty) = 0$, $G(\infty) = 0$.

And then converted that into a system of 1st order ODEs featuring $F$, $F_2$, $G$ and $G_2$:

$$\begin{align*}F' &= F_2\\
G' &= G_2\\
F_2' &= -G^2 + F^2 - F_2F^2\\
G_2' &= 2FG - F^2G_2
\end{align*}$$

However here is where I've hit a wall. I first tried solving them analytically using DSolve, however that failed to return an explicit solution, so after some reading I discovered that I could try using a numerical shooting method. Google seems to indicate that ode45 is my best bet, however I'm not particularly adept at MatLab, and I've been tearing my hair out trying to understand how to implement it successfully.

From what I've read in other papers, some have had success using initial conditions of F2'(0) = 0.52 and G2'(0) = -0.61 and a replacement of infinity with 20, if that's any help at all.

Bottom line is, I really just can't seem to get my head around how to solve this in MatLab. If anyone could show me how to, or at least demonstrate the proper syntax for describing this type of system, I'd hugely appreciate it.

Thanks for reading

Mike

Comment: Here's an issue: `ode45` is an initial value solver. But you have a boundary value problem. So what you need to implement is a shooting method. Let me see if I can't convert one for you.

Comment: I'd very much appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: I can put together a shooting method no problem, but the equations you have written do not have enough information (and may not be correct). Double check your work. The typical rotating disk flow is a 5-state system, as @LutzL mentioned below. And you need to make a distinction with your initial conditions: we would have initial conditions for $F$ and $F' =F_2$ only, not $F_2'$, and likewise for $G$.

Comment: Hi Arkamis, I appreciate the help you've given so far; you are correct, the full system is
 
F' = F2;

G' = G2;

F2' = -G^2 + F^2 - F2*F^2;

G2' = 2*F*G - F^2*G2;

H' = -2*F;

With initial conditions F(0) = 0; G(0) = 1; H(0) = 1; F(inf) = 0; G(inf) = 0;

You are also right about there not being intial conditions for F2' and G2' 
- I meant to write that at F'(0)=0.52 and G'(0)=-0.61 although I cannot vouch for those myself, as I simply found them in a paper on the topic 

(http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:722139/FULLTEXT01.pdf) 

as having been initial guesses, thought it'd be useful.

Comment: Great; I'll crank out a solution. It won't be efficient but this should work

Comment: See this article on [Boundary-Value Problems](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/boundary-value-problems.html) from The MathWorks. Try some of the example. The `fsbvp` example (`edit fsbvp`) in particular handles infinite boundary conditions.

Comment: I've run the equations against a shooting method and I am not getting good results. I suspect the equations are not properly written. And while I appreciate the link to the paper, I have no inclination to read the whole thing to figure out where you get those from, particularly as you are using a whole different nomenclature. I can help, but I cannot help until the question is posed correctly.

Comment: Hi Arkamis, I just want to say thank you very much for taking the time to actually go through this and try to help me find a solution. 

I should say that I suspect I know the reason you're not getting good results- the ODEs themselves are not the whole picture; they then feed into the three components of velocity, u, v, and w, where: 

u = omega * r * F(n);  

v = omega * r * G(n);  

w = sqrt(omega * v) * H(n);

where omega is the angular velocity of the fluid, r is the radial distance from the centre, and n is an axial coordinate given by n = z*sqrt(omega/v) and z is the axial distance.

Comment: I apologise if failing to add that made things less clear for you, but the fact is that I didn't expect you to go so far as to attempt a method of solving it for me- I had planned on feeding the results of the shooting method into the equations myself.
Thank you for going above and beyond what I had expected, and I'm sorry if my failure to explain things fully wasted your time.

Comment: Also, just to say that even if you didn't want to put any further time into this I'd understand, but if you could at least show me the code for how you put it against the shooting method (or show me how to write it myself) I could at least keep bashing at it myself until I got somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about your elimination of $H$? Could you explain how you come to replace $H=-F^2$, because that implies $H'=-2F·F'$, which is still quadratic in $F$. Quasi-archeological reconstruction suggests that the following procedure is closest to the original system in the paper.

```
function doty = odefunc(t,y)
    F=y(1); F1=y(2); G=y(3); G1=y(4); H=y(5)
    doty = [ F1, -G^2 + F^2 - F1*H,
             G1, 2*F*G - H*G1,
             2*F ]
end
```

This now is a dimension 5 system, thus requires 5 initial values.

---

Using the structure of the system in the comments, and [the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266118/trouble-with-derivatives) closer to the original paper, one can reconstruct that the correct system has indeed the structure
$$\begin{align}
Z'' &= Z^2-HZ',&~~~ Z=F+iG&=U+i(V+1),
\\
H'&=2F,& ~~~ H&=-W
\end{align}$$
as one could expect from a rotational setup.

Using a boundary value solver this gives a solution over the interval $[0,8]$ that has first and final vector

```
[-7.47756897e-23  1.00000000e+00  5.10116328e-01 -6.15849164e-01  0.00000000e+00]
[ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -7.04991619e-04 -9.34891188e-04  8.74618873e-01]
```

with a plot

[image]

However, the python script fails fatally for larger intervals, so convergence towards a solution with right boundary at infinity is unclear.