# Convert to first order system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this system of equation where I need to convert them to system of first order.

So, here is the original equation.

```
Equation:
2*U + x*(1-n/(n+1))*U' + W' = 0
U^2 - (V+1)^2 + [W+(1-n/(n+1))*x*U]*U' - {(U'^2+V'^2)^((n-1)/2)*U''+U'*[(n-1)*(U'U''+V'V'')*(U'^2+V'^2)^((n-3)/2)]}=0
2*U*(V+1) + [W+(1-n/(n+1))*x*U]*V' - {(U'^2+V'^2)^((n-1)/2)*V''+V'*[(n-1)*(U'U''+V'V'')*(U'^2+V'^2)^((n-3)/2)]}=0

bc:
U(0)=V(0)=W(0)=0, U(infinity)=0, V(infinity)=-1.
```

I let,

```
Y(1) = W, Y(2) = U, Y(3) = U', Y(4) = V, Y(5) = V'.
```

hence, I got,

```
Y(1)' = -2Y(2)+x(1-n/(n+1))Y(3)
Y(2)' = Y(3)
Y(3)' = Y(2)^2-(Y(4)+1)^2+(Y(1)+x(1-n/(n+1))Y(2))Y(3)-Y(3)(n-1)(Y(3)^2+Y(5)^2)^((n-3)/2)Y(5)V''/(Y(3)^2+Y(5)^2)^((n-1)/2)+Y(3)(n-1)(Y(3)^2+Y(5)^2)((n-3)/2)
Y(4)' = Y(5)
Y(5)' = -2Y(2)(Y(4)+1)+(Y(1)+x(1-n/(n+1))Y(2))Y(5)-Y(5)(n-1)(Y(3)^2+Y(5)^2)^((n-3)/2)Y(3)U''/(Y(3)^2+Y(5)^2)^((n-1)/2)+Y(5)(n-1)(Y(3)^2+Y(5)^2)((n-3)/2)
```

So, the problem is that which make me confused, for `Y(3)'`, as you can see, there is `V''` there. And for `Y(5)'`, there is `U''`. How should I write this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write equations on this site. It'll make your equations much easier to read and more likely to attract answerers.

Comment: And note that $n/n=1$ always, so that `(1-n/n+1) == 1`.

Comment: Now it is better, but I think that originally it was `(1-n)/(n+1)`. Can you give a link to the paper or task that this system comes from?

Comment: Might be related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259440/solving-a-system-of-two-second-order-odes-using-runge-kutta-method-ode45-in-ma and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266118/trouble-with-derivatives-using-newton-raphson-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

Let's decompose this into smaller parts:

Define

```
a(x) = ((1-n)/(n+1))*x
b(U',V')=(U'^2+V'^2)^((n-1)/2)
```

Then identify that in the last two equation inside `{…}` are the derivatives of the expressions

```
X = U'*b(U',V')
Y = V'*b(U',V')
```

To reverse these to get `U',V'` in dependence of `X,Y` try

```
U'=c*X, 
V'=c*Y,
```

to get the identity

```
X = c*X*b(c*X,c*Y)=c^((n+1)/2)*X*b(X,Y)
```

and thus

```
c = b(X,Y)^(-2/(n+1)) = (X^2+Y^2)^(-(n-1)/(n+1))
```

The original equations can now be rewritten using those expressions and reordered to give the remaining derivatives

```
W' = -2*U - a(x)*U'
X' = U^2 - (V+1)^2 + [W+a(x)*U]*U'
Y' = 2*U*(V+1) + [W+a(x)*U]*V'
```

In some pseudo-quasi-code this would be implemented as

```
function odefunc(x,state)
    U,V,W,X,Y = state
    a = ((1-n)/(n+1))*x
    c = (X*X+Y*Y)^((1-n)/(n+1))

    dU = c*X
    dV = c*Y

    dW = -2*U - a*dU
    dX = U^2 - (V+1)^2 + (W+a*U)*dU
    dY = 2*U*(V+1) + (W+a*U)*dV

    return [ dU, dV, dW, dX, dY]
end function
```